# Chains and cochains: integer versus real coefficients

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

Let a real, smooth manifold $M$ be given.  For each non-negative integer $k$, let a singular $k$-cube on $M$ be a continuous mapping $c:[0,1]\to M$.  Let $C_k(M,\mathbb Z)$ denote the set of formal linear combinations of singular $k$-cubes with integer coefficients, namely the set of $k$-chains with integer coefficients, and let $C_k(M,\mathbb R)$ denote the set of $k$-chains with real coefficients.  Let $C^k(M,\mathbb Z)$ and $C^k(M, \mathbb R)$ denote the corresponding duals, namely sets of cochains.

**Question.** I'd like to know if given a cochain $X\in C^k(M, \mathbb Z)$, there is a unique cochain $\bar X\in C^k(M, \mathbb R)$ such that $\bar X$ "agrees" with $X$ on chains with integer coefficients.

It has been suggested to me that this question is related to the so-called "Universal Coefficient Theorem," but as I'm not particularly familiar with this stuff, it's not clear to me if that's the case.

Comment: Sure.  Just send integer-valued chains to the same values as $X$ and extend linearly.

Comment: @MartianInvader Well then.  That's rather embarrassing.  Thanks.